# how to move an image up, down, left or right as the player wants?

Tags: android

I have project this semester and it is an Android Game with 2 players (user and device), What i want is if the user selected and object (image) on the screen and moved it using his finger to any side it moves to the side and save the new coordinators in array ?

Shall i use `OnDragListener`, `GestureListener` or what ?

Thanks

Comment: I think this is a good idea https://guides.codepath.com/android/Gestures-and-Touch-Events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a good idea [Gestures-and-Touch-Events](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Gestures-and-Touch-Events)